# Использование переменных в twig

Tags: twig, php, html, шаблоны, symfony2

Добрый день. При выполнении кода ругается

```
    {% set num = (category|length) // 3 %}

<ul class="uList1 ">

    {% for item in category %}
    {% if loop.index is divisibleby(num) %}
        </ul>
        <ul class="uList1 ">
    {% endif %}
    <li><a href="#">{{ item.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: Division by zero")

Не воспринимает как число. number_format тоже пробовал. Как быть?

Answer (score 2):

```
{% if loop.index is divisibleby(num) %}
    </ul>
    <ul class="uList1 ">
{% endif %}
```

Для таких штук придумали [batch](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html)

> Не воспринимает как число

Воспринимает как ноль. Я, кстати, не уверен, что там нужны скобки. В общем, простой проверки на пустоту категории должно быть достаточно.

Comment: Я вот с batch не разобрался для моего примера. Подскажите, как мне быть в моем случае? Мне нужно, чтобы было максимум три группы <ul></ul> списков. Значит количество категорий мне надо распределить равномерно на три части.
Допустим, если category|length = 13, то получается 4, 4 и 5 .